# how to resolve htaccess redirect issue with website

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

My website is not stripping the text in * condition.

Website URL is like http://www. domain.com/search/adasd
I want to redirect it to https://www. domain.com/noindex-page

Using below redirect rule

```
RewriteRule ^search/\*$ https://www. domain.com/noindex-page? [L,R=301]
```

but it is redirecting to https://www. domain.com/noindex-pageadasd and giving 404 not found.

Please suggest how to strip adasd from this.

Using * is necessary as there are number of URLs with this prefix.

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for sharing your htaccess file in your question, keep it up. Could you please 2 things here, 1st- I believe space coming in between your www. and domain I believe its a typo in your question(but in your real rules you don't have spaces)? 2nd- Is file named `noindex-page` is present in same path where htaccess file is present? Kindly confirm these once, thank you.

Comment: Space is just for typing here.

Comment: Yes page is there

Answer (score 1):

Based on your shown samples could you please try following. I believe problem in your regex `\*` is you have escaped `*` which means it is NO longer matching everything after search keyword and is treated as a literal as `*` hence it may not be working. Since you are looking for anything after `search` keyword then we could simply check if uri starts from `search` here.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^search https://www.yourdomain.com/noindex-page? [L,R=301,NC]
```